# Order of DESCRIPTION Imports: and NAMESPACE import() in R 2.14.0 package checking

Tags: r, package

I'm trying to chase down what seems to be a conflict between function names as I check a package.  I may eventually ask directly about the problem, but first, I am wondering about three things, none of which seem to be mentioned in R-exts:

1. The packages listed in DESCRIPTION: Imports and NAMESPACE imports() should be the same, right?
2. Within either list, does the order of importing matter?  If so, is there any general advice about how to order them?
3. I use R --vanilla CMD check pkg_name to avoid having my .Rprofile interfere.  When my .Rprofile is active and contains library(pkg_name) statements, does the order of those matter?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You asked three questions.

### 1. List packages in `DESCRIPTION` as well as `NAMESPACE`

Each package listed in `DESCRIPTION` `Imports:` must have a matching entry `NAMESPACE` `import(...)`.  The entry in `DESCRIPTION` may contain version information, but in `NAMESPACE` you only name the package.

*Note for the unwary:  Spell `Imports` with capital `I` and trailing `s` in DESCRIPTION*

For example:

**DESCRIPTION**

```
Imports:
    stringr (>= 0.5)
```

**NAMESPACE**

```
import(stringr)
```

### 2. Order matters

Packages that you `load` or `import` later masks packages that were loaded or imported earlier.  This only matters if you import packages that have export a function with identical name.

For example, both `lattice` and `ggplot2` export a `layer` function.  Thus if you first import `lattice` and then `ggplot2`, it means that  `ggplot2::layer` will mask `lattice::layer`.

In other words, using `layer` will refer to `ggplot2::layer`.  If you want to refer to the `lattice` version you need to explicitly refer to `lattice::layer` in your function.

### 3. The order of loading packages also matter

For the same reason, the order of loading packages (either in a script or in .Rprofile) matters.  Any new package that you load will mask functions with the same name in previously loaded packages.

When this happens, R does the sensible thing and tells you about it in a console message.

Here is an example of masking that occurs when loading the `reshape` package, which depends on `plyr` but also masks some functions in `plyr`:

```
library(reshape)
Loading required package: plyr

Attaching package: 'plyr'

The following object(s) are masked from 'package:braidppt':

    .


Attaching package: 'reshape'

The following object(s) are masked from 'package:plyr':

    rename, round_any
```

Comment: Thank you Andrie... your answer was very clear, and confirmed what I thought was going on.  Now I have to figure out the order things need to be in.  Maybe it's too obvious, but a note about this in R-exts would probably be useful.

Comment: Looking around a bit more, I see >conflicts(detail = TRUE) can help me find the problem.

Comment: Note that if you have conflicts, you should probably use `importsFrom` to just import the selected functions from each package